# How to target multiple browsers in Angular 11 project using scss

Tags: css, angular, sass

for example:
i am animating the ::placeholder pseudo element on ::focus

```
  input::placeholder{
       color: grey;
       transition: all 400ms ease;
       position: absolute;
       top: 35%;
       font-size: 15px;
  }

   input:focus::placeholder{
       color: green;
       top: 0%;
       font-size: 10px;
       position: relative;
  }
```

in Chrome it works perfectly fine, but in Firefox and Safari does not work,
anyone can help please, i really need to be able to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use vendor prefixes to accomplish what you want.

In the given example, to work with Firefox, you should use `::-moz-placeholder`.

You can find more about vendor prefixes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you just need to add firefox support to the `.browserslistrc` file.